# MongoDB find in the collection and display the column without knowing what is in it. Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I have a collection in MongoDB, I need to find a collection where: `"user_id" : 965554753650192394`, and in this collection there is a column with `"coins"' and I need to display the data of this column

I tried to implement it via

```py
user = collection.find_one({})
print(user)
```

But this method is not suitable because initially you need to know the contents of the column.
That is, I need to find the `"user_id"`, and then find the `"coins"` column data in this collection and display them in the column and display data from this column(python)

Comment: "_I need to find a collection_"? Do you mean document? I also don't understand what you mean "_then find the coins column data in this collection_". Are you referring to fields in a document? Finally, you tagged Mongoose but that is an ORM for Node and you seem to be asking about Python

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are trying to do, could you give a couple of sample documents, a sample query, what you are currently getting, and what you would like to get

Comment: _I need to find a collection where: user_id : 965554753650192394_ So search for that user_id.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Does `result = collection.find_one({"user_id" : 965554753650192394}, {"coins": 1})` get close to what you are looking for?